# Using GDAL and ArcPy for Reprojection?

Tags: arcpy, gdal, gdalwarp

**GOAL**: Take a raster and reproject it from one co-ordinate set to another and also change the pixel size while I am at it by using GDAL.

**WHY**: I am trying to use gdal to speed up multiple rasters having to be reprojected which is taking a long time in ArcPy.

**Current progress**: I can get this to happen nicely by using ArcPy and the following segment of code:

```
arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(in.tif, out.tif, "PROJCS['WGS_1984_UTM_zone_48N',GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['false_easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['false_northing',0.0],PARAMETER['central_meridian',105.0],PARAMETER['scale_factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['latitude_of_origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]", "NEAREST", "100", "", "", "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]")
```

**The GDAL code**: I am using the segment of code below to hopefully try to obtain the same result.

```
call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalwarp.exe',"-s_srs", "EPSG:4326","-t_srs","EPSG:32648","-tr","100","100","-r","near","-srcnodata","0.0","-dstnodata","0.0","-of","GTiFF",in.tif, out.tif])
```

Actual result from gdal: A dataset that is reprojected to the correct co-ord system and pixel resized to the desired size.

**The problem**: The raster dataset when opened and worked with keeps showing that the min and max values it contains is the nodata value of +-3.40282e+038

**The key point**: Does anyone have any idea why this is not working correctly in gdal?

---

While trying different different options I found that by running

```
call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalwarp.exe',"-s_srs", "EPSG:4326","-t_srs","EPSG:32648",,"-srcnodata","0.0","-dstnodata","0.0","-of","GTiFF",in.tif, out.tif])
```

I found that the resulting cell size from the projection is ~1000x1000 so I don't know why it won't let me scale to a smaller cell size?

**Extra checks**:

1. I have checked [the spatial reference website](http://spatialreference.org/) to ensure that the EPSG co-ord I am using as the correct ones.
2. And as far as I can tell from the [gdalwarp info page](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) the code should work nice.

Comment: Could you say what goes wrong with the first command? Does the image look otherwise good but the nodata value is not 0 as you wished? What does `gdalinfo -hist`report about the pixel size and histogram? Have you tried to use integer numbers for nodata `-srsnodata 0 -dstnodata 0`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ArcGIS is having trouble understanding the output rasters NoData values and the data range.  Run *Calculate Statistics* on the output rasters.  From *ArcToolbox - Data Management - Raster Properties - Calculate Statistics*

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `AutoCreateWarpedVRT` function to reproject the raster.

It follows the following structure:

`AutoCreateWarpedVRT(src_ds, [src_wkt], [dst_wkt], [eReamspleAlg], [maxerror])`

where:

- `src_ds` is the dataset you want to reproject.
- `src_wkt` is the WKT representation of the source spatial reference
  system. The default is None, in which case it will use the SRS
  information from the source raster.
- `dst_wkt` is the WKT representation of the desired spatial reference
  system. The default is None, in which case no reprojection will
  occur.
- `eResampleAlg` is the resampling methods (see attached image). The
  default is GRA_NearestNeighbour.
- `maxerror` is the maximum amount of error, in pixels, that you want to
  allow. The default is 0, for an exact calculation.

[image]

A simple example script using this function to 'reproject' to WGS84 would be:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import osr
import os

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.SetWellKnownGeogCS('WGS84')
old_ds = gdal.Open(fn)
vrt_ds = gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(old_ds, None, srs.ExportToWkt(), gdal.GRA_Bilinear)
ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('gtiff').CreateCopy(new_fn, vrt_ds)

ds.FlushCache()

del old_ds, vrt_ds, ds
```

Be careful to select a proper resampling method depending on the data you have.

**Note:** the image and the function description were taken from the Geoprocessing with Python (Chris Garrard) book. See: https://www.manning.com/books/geoprocessing-with-python

Then you could resample your raster using the following example:

```
from osgeo import gdal

in_ds = gdal.Open(fn)
in_band = in_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
out_rows = in_band.YSize * 2  # Change this value depending on how many rows you want the output to be
out_columns = in_band.XSize * 2  # Change this value depending on how many columns you want the output to be

gtiff_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
out_ds = gtiff_driver.Create(new_fn, out_columns, out_rows)
out_ds.SetProjection(in_ds.GetProjection())
geotransform = list(in_ds.GetGeoTransform())

# Edit the geotransform so pixels are one-quarter previous size
# You can change this depending on the size you want to resample to
geotransform[1] /= 2
geotransform[5] /= 2
out_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)

data = in_band.ReadAsArray(buf_xsize=out_columns, buf_ysize=out_rows)
out_band = out_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
out_band.WriteArray(data)

out_band.FlushCache()

del out_ds
```

or simply specify the `win_xsize` and `win_ysize` parameters in the `ReadAsArray()` method, which should automatically resample to a smaller size if the array you're trying to store the data in is bigger than the original data size.

The method structure is as follows:

`band.ReadAsArray([xoff], [yoff], [win_xsize], [win_ysize], [buf_xsize],[buf_ysize], [buf_obj])`